# Defining Apigee Target Servers hosts (the right way) in an HA Architecture

Tags: apigee

I'm on 14.04 On-Prem

I have an Active and DR setup
see here: http://www.slideshare.net/michaelgeiser/apigee-dc-failover

When I failover to the DR site, I update my DNS entry (at Akamai)

Virtual hosts work fine; Target Servers are giving me a headache

How can I setup and work with the **Target Servers** so I do not have to modify the Proxy API bundle but have traffic flow to the right VIP based on the DC?

I prefer ***not*** to do something like MyService-Target-dc1 and MyService-Target-dc2 and use the deploy script to modify the target name in the bundle.

I do not want to have a JavaScript that is modifies the target or anything else in the Proxy API, I need to define this in Environment setup.

I also cannot put the two DCs each into a separate Org; I need to use the same API Key when I move between the Active and DR sites; different Orgs mean different API Keys (right?).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

One option is to modify the DNS lookup on each set of MP per DC so that a name like 'myservice.target.dc' resolves to different VIP. You'll of course want to document this well 
since this, especially since this is external to the Apigee product.

I know you weren't too keen on modifying the target, but if you were open to that option, you could try using the host header of an ELB in front (if you have one) or client IP address (e.g., in geo-based routing) to identify which DC a call is passing through.  From there, you can modify the target URL.

And yes, different Orgs do mean different API keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Named Target Servers. They are part of the Load Balancing function but you can set them up individually and have different targets for different environments  See:

**Load Balancing Across Backend Servers**
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/load-balancing-across-backend-servers

**Create a Named Target Server**
http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/environments/%7Benv_name%7D/targetservers